# Adjective Nominalization in Python NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

Is there a way to obtain Wordnet adjective nominalizations using NLTK?
For example, for `happy` the desired output would be `happiness`.

I tried to dig around, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 4):

The quick and dirty answer is that wordnet [does this already](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o7=&o5=&o1=1&o6=&o4=1&o3=&s=happy&i=7&h=10010000000#c):

> - <adj.all>S: (adj) happy (enjoying or showing or marked by joy or pleasure)
>     "a happy smile"; "spent many happy
>     days on the beach"; "a happy marriage"
>
>   - attribute
>
>     - <noun.state>S: (n) happiness, felicity (state of
>         well-being characterized by emotions
>         ranging from contentment to intense
>         joy)
>     - <noun.feeling>S: (n) happiness (emotions experienced when
>         in a state of well-being)
>   - derivationally related form
>
>     - <noun.state> W: (n) happiness [Related to: happy] (state
>         of well-being characterized by
>         emotions ranging from contentment to
>         intense joy)
>     - <noun.feeling> W: (n) happiness [Related to: happy]
>         (emotions experienced when in a state
>         of well-being)

The remaining question is how to do this programmatically (without web-scraping).

### Added:

The wordnet library wrapper tool is pretty powerful and demonstrates what appears to be the breadth of the C library interface:

```
$ wn happy
No information available for noun happy
No information available for verb happy
Information available for adj happy
    -antsa      Antonyms
    -synsa      Synonyms (ordered by estimated frequency)
    -attra      Attributes
    -deria      Derived Forms
    -famla      Familiarity & Polysemy Count
    -grepa      List of Compound Words
    -over       Overview of Senses
$ wn happy -deria -n1
Derived Forms of adj happy
Sense 1
happy (vs. unhappy)
       RELATED TO->(noun) happiness#1
           => happiness, felicity
       RELATED TO->(noun) happiness#2
           => happiness
```

So, Pythonically, you could either `subprocess` to the wn command which is kinda sloppy, or use the wordnet facilities already built into NLTK.

On ubuntu (and presumably debian) the wordnet libraries and tools are conveniently available with:

```
sudo apt-get install wordnet wordnet-dev
```

Alas:

```
$ wn pythonic
No information available for pythonic
```